# Swift 3 retrieving, editing and sending back HTML

Tags: html, swift3, uitextview, html-rendering

in my application I am retrieving HTML text from the server and I am presenting it in a UITextView.

I have used [this following example](http://sketchytech.blogspot.gr/2016/02/swift-from-html-to-nsattributedtext-and.html) in order to turn the HTML to an attributed string for rendering it into the UITextView and then converting the attributed string back to HTML in order to send it to the server. Following this approach, the HTML which is being sent back to the system is different that the HTML which I have retrieved. The format is the same, but the tags are different. I realised this after implementing the mention functionality. In this I am supposed to send a class mention to the server. However, this is not possible because the actual HTML is being altered by the attributed string.

Is it possible to get the HTML and present it in a text view, edit it and send back the same HTML containing all the edits back to the server?

Thank you in advance!! :)

Comment: You could create a webView with a textarea element, onload `textArea.innerHTML = *html*` then when sending back, `let html = webView.evaluateJavascript("textArea.innerHTML")`

Comment: @JacobBoyd how can I add a textarea in a webview?

Comment: You could create the HTML document holding the textArea, and bundle it with your app.  Then just load that html file into a WKWebView/UIWebView

Comment: @JacobBoyd the thing is that I want to edit the HTML in the position of the cursor. So I have to tap on the position and then enter the text, just like in a UITextView.